# Regex loops continuously without terminating to find a match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find the matching positions, I have tried with

```
function myFunction() {
  var myvar_thru_textbox="u?"

  var ptrn = new RegExp(myvar_thru_textbox, "gim");

  var match;

  while ((match = ptrn.exec("color colour")) != null) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(match));   
  }

}
```

This code produces infinite output with the string ""

When the pattern is changed to "ou?" it produces a correct output, Why the ? character goes to infinity if preceded with a single character ?

I was expecting to produce "" or "u" only when "u?" regex is used.

Comment: /u?/ will match both an empty string as well as "u". That empty string is a problem as there are infinite instances of them in any given string.

Comment: Check to see if it's empty first and, if it is, reject it.

Comment: But this will continue for ever, this would also prevent underlying non empty matching texts

Comment: In your example, why can't you use just `"u"` rather than `"u?"`? I don't see a good reason to search for empty string fragments.

Comment: No, this is for an application and cannot anticipate the client inputs...

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. You're actually asking how to sanitize user provided regular expressions. This is a variation of the Halting Problem and doesn't have a solution. Generally, a good enough work around is to cancel after a number of iterations or amount of time has passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec),

> JavaScript RegExp objects are stateful when they have the global or sticky flags set (e.g. `/foo/g` or `/foo/y`). They store a `lastIndex` from the previous match.
>
> ...
>
> If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and updates the `lastIndex` property of the regular expression object.

Now imagine what happens on the first iteration. The regex finds a zero width match at index 0, so it sets the `lastIndex` to 0. Then on the second iteration, it starts searching from 0, where it finds another zero-width match, so it sets `lastIndex` to 0 again. And the cycle continues.

Therefore, you should put an if statement there to check if the match is zero-width. If it is, increment the last index, so that it doesn't give you the same match again.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ptrn = new RegExp("u?", "gim");

  var match;
  var i = 0;

  while ((match = ptrn.exec("color colour")) != null) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(match));
    if (match.index == ptrn.lastIndex) {
      ptrn.lastIndex++;
    }

  }

}
myFunction()
```

Answer (score -1):

`?` means "zero or one". `u?` means "match on a single instance of `u` or a single instance of nothing." So, it's not surprising that `u?` matches your string infinitely many times. I guess I wouldn't have predicted that, but it's not alarming.

When you change your regex to `ou?`, that means "*require* an `o`, optionally followed by a `u`". It *does not* mean "find zero or one `ou` combination." There are two `o`s in your string, which means it will match twice.

Comment: I knew that, But I am seeking a solution to find the matching text without bypassing the underlying non empty text. The expected output must be "" and "u"  only.

Comment: Your question is "Why the ? character goes to infinity if preceded with a single character ?" I have answered that question. Your post does not tell us what result you were hoping to achieve, and I don't read minds, so I didn't figure out how to build the thing you secretly want.

Comment: You can refer Sweepers answer above.